# Create a download button in WCFM frontend manager

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce

I've created a product custom field in WCFM frontend manager, In that field I selected Html type and then I added the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .download{
            width: auto;
            background-color: royalblue;
            color: white;
            font-size: 20px;
            border:none;
            padding-left: 30px;
            padding-right: 30px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            padding-top: 5px;
        }

        .download:hover{
          
            background-color:turquoise
        }
    </style>
    
    <a href="wptbox/mouaz/socks-setup-template.rar" download>
      
      <button type="submit" class="download">Download</button>
    </a>
    
</body>
</html>
```

That code is for create a button to download .rar file when clicking on it, but the code not working, where is the problem here?

Comment: We will need more details than "it's not working". Is the button showing up? Is the request for the file send when you press it?

Comment: Yes the button is appear, but when clicking on the button, nothing happening, I have just tried the following:    <a href="wptbox/mouaz/socks-setup-template.rar
" download="socks-setup-template.rar">Download</a>
      
      <button type="submit" class="download">Download</button>
    </a>

Comment: It's strange that you use a button inside of an anchor. Try it without the inner button. Can you access your file by just using the file path with the browser?

Comment: First off, sorry for late, the link has worked well , I used the URL of the file using the media library, and removed the button element. But I don't understand why the button element/tag didn't working, how to make the link a button?

Comment: Typically you have to choose whether to use an anchor/link (`<a></a>`) or a button (`<button></button>`). When dealing with forms there is also `<input type="submit" ...>`. The second step is to apply styling with css. You can make all those options look like a button.